# When viewing products in the category view, I would like to be able to have a “Quantity” box

Tags: magento

In MAGENTO,When viewing products in the category view, I would like to be able to have a “Quantity” box that allows the user to enter the quantity needed before clicking the “Add to Cart” button. How can I show this?

Answer (score 0):

In List.phtml file find the below line

```
  <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

and replace it with

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

     <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
       <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
       <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo  ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
      <button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
      </form>
```

Comment: I tried this code but it seems it does not work. The "Add to Cart" buttom disappeared.List.phtml is located at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml